# Inline assembly in Haskell

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, assembly, inline-assembly, ghc

Can I somehow use inline assembly in Haskell (similar to what GCC does for C)?

I want to compare my Haskell code to the reference implementation (ASM) and this seems the most straightforward way. I guess I could just [call Haskell from C](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Calling_Haskell_from_C) and use GCC inline assembly, but I'm still interested if I can do it the other way around.

*(I'm on Linux/x86)*

Comment: @Don Stewart That link is broken

Comment: Note, if you're comparing performance of Haskell against inline assembly, I'd first actually look at the assembly GHC generates (with e.g. -O2 -fllvm), using the [ghc-core](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-core) tool

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two ways:

- Call C via the FFI, and use inline assembly on the C side.
- Write a CMM fragment that calls C (without the FFI), and uses inlined assembly.

Both solutions use inline assembly on the C side. The former is the most idiomatic. Here's an example, from the [rdtsc](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rdtsc) package:

cycles.h:

```
static __inline__ ticks getticks(void)
{
     unsigned int tbl, tbu0, tbu1;

     do {
      __asm__ __volatile__ ("mftbu %0" : "=r"(tbu0));
      __asm__ __volatile__ ("mftb %0" : "=r"(tbl));
      __asm__ __volatile__ ("mftbu %0" : "=r"(tbu1));
     } while (tbu0 != tbu1);

     return (((unsigned long long)tbu0) << 32) | tbl;
}
```

rdtsc.c:

```
unsigned long long rdtsc(void)
{    
  return getticks();
}
```

rdtsc.h:

```
unsigned long long rdtsc(void);
```

rdtsc.hs:

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "rdtsc.h" rdtsc :: IO Word64
```

Finally:

- A slightly non-obvious solution is to use the [LLVM](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm) or [Harpy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/harpy) packages to call some generated assembly.